# tumblr iphone integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tumblr, nsmutableurlrequest

Hi i have done with status update in tumbler but i am facing problem when i am sending photo in the form of data, as shown below.

```
-(IBAction)sendPhoto
{
    NSString *email           = @"user_name@gmail.com";
    NSString *password        = @"password";
    NSString *sendType = @"photo";

    UIImage *imageMS = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Submit.png"];
    NSData *photoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageMS)];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/api/write"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *request_body = [NSString 
            stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&type=%@&data=%@",
            [email           stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
            [password        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
            [sendType        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
            photoData];
    [request setHTTPBody:[request_body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [web loadRequest:request];
}
```

But it is not getting updated. Why?

Comment: Also you should not post your actual username and password, I would suggest changing these right away.

Comment: ok i will change , if you know please help me anything regarding uploading photo to tumblr .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer proved to be incorrect, but the OP posted a link to code that he said fixed his problem. I have copied that code below so that future searchers can find it easily, since I know how frustrating it can be to see your problem described and find a link to the solution only to have that link be dead.

Code based on http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=427513:

```
- (BOOL)sendPhotoToTumblr:(NSString *)photo usingEmail:(NSString *)tumblrEmail andPassword:(NSString *)tumblrPassword withCaption:(NSString *)caption;
{
    //get image data from file
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:photo];  
    //stop on error
    if (!imageData) return NO;

    //Create dictionary of post arguments
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"password",@"type",@"caption",nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            tumblrEmail,
            tumblrPassword,
            @"photo", caption, nil];
    NSDictionary *keysDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    //create tumblr photo post
    NSURLRequest *tumblrPost = [self createTumblrRequest:keysDict withData:imageData];
    [keysDict release];     

    //send request, return YES if successful
    tumblrConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:tumblrPost delegate:self];
    if (!tumblrConnection) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
        return NO;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Request submitted");
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            [tumblrConnection release];
        return YES;
    }
}


-(NSURLRequest *)createTumblrRequest:(NSDictionary *)postKeys withData:(NSData *)data
{
    //create the URL POST Request to tumblr
    NSURL *tumblrURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/api/write"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *tumblrPost = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tumblrURL];
    [tumblrPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //Add the header info
    NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
    [tumblrPost addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //create the body
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //add key values from the NSDictionary object
    NSEnumerator *keys = [postKeys keyEnumerator];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [postKeys count]; i++) {
        NSString *tempKey = [keys nextObject];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",tempKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[postKeys objectForKey:tempKey]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    //add data field and file data
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //add the body to the post
    [tumblrPost setHTTPBody:postBody];

    return tumblrPost;
}
```

I have modified the above code to eliminate some memory issues and to add some parameters to make this a more generic/flexible solution. However, if someone would like the original code as posted on that site, just look through this answer's edit revisions.

Comment: i have added this code but the contents of photoString becoming null

Comment: Now i am able to send photo successfully i am using the code from this link . http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=427513 .

Comment: @RameshIndia , I follow the code in your link but still i'm not able to post the photo...if you don't mind can you send your code to my Mail(ashoksoft.yes@gmail.com).. Thank you RameshIndia.....

Comment: Hi theChrisKent, can u please tell me how to get the blog name. Please see this question once . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728635/how-can-i-fetch-the-unique-blog-names-in-tumblr     Please tell me how to get the blog name    Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)'s ASIFormDatRequest makes this sort of thing much easier.